# Python function alters list of tuples each having two tuples incorrectly

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def calculate_cross_rate(currency0, currency1, data):
    conversion = float(data['USD%s' % currency1]) / float(data['USD%s' % currency0])
    return float("{:.2f}".format(conversion))

def get_cross_rates(currencies_combinations, data):
    """
    currencies_combination is 
    [({'symbol': '€', 'name': 'Euro', 'code': 'EUR'}, {'symbol': '\u200e₸', 'name': 'Kazakhstani Tenge', 'code': 'KZT'}),
     ({'symbol': '€', 'name': 'Euro', 'code': 'EUR'}, {'symbol': 'Bs', 'name': 'Bolivian Boliviano', 'code': 'BOB'}),
     ({'symbol': '\u200e₸', 'name': 'Kazakhstani Tenge', 'code': 'KZT'}, {'symbol': 'Bs', 'name': 'Bolivian Boliviano', 'code': 'BOB'})]
    """
    for currencies in currencies_combinations:
        currency0, currency1 = currencies[0]['code'], currencies[1]['code']
        output0 = calculate_cross_rate(currency0, currency1, data)
        currencies[0]['conversion'] = output0
        print(currency0, currency1, output0)
        output1 = calculate_cross_rate(currency1, currency0, data)
        currencies[1]['conversion'] = output1
        print(currency1, currency0, output1)
    for currencies in currencies_combinations:
        print(currencies[0]['code'], currencies[1]['code'], currencies[0]['conversion'])
        print(currencies[1]['code'], currencies[0]['code'], currencies[1]['conversion'])
    return currencies_combinations



Output
EUR KZT 0.75
KZT EUR 1.33
EUR BOB 0.67
BOB EUR 1.5
KZT BOB 0.89
BOB KZT 1.12

EUR KZT 0.67
KZT EUR 0.89
EUR BOB 0.67
BOB EUR 1.12
KZT BOB 0.89
BOB KZT 1.12
```

We are adding a new key 'conversion'. However, when we print out the same key and value, it is different.

Comment: You have a list... of tuples... of dicts?

Comment: I can't reproduce your result. Using a dummy calculate_cross_rate function returning a random number, for me it works as expected.

Comment: Could you post a minimal fully reproducible code?

Comment: @adrin added more code

Comment: @iamkhush you need to post some minimal values of `data` as well. Something I could actually run, to reproduce what you're getting.

Comment: @adrin did you use list of tuples of dicts ? Because I just now used list of list of dicts, and things were working alright

Comment: This is the code which works: https://bpaste.net/show/d76b64026eaa